# Does a Twitter Meta site exist?

Tags: twitter

Is there a meta site (or something equivalent) for Twitter?

For example: https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is rather node like. Not really found in one specific area. We are talking close to 200 Million users. So they employ the [Twicket](https://support.twitter.com/forms) for bugs, support and feature requests. Turn around time can be from a day to a week.

You can say the moderators (or tags) of *meta* are

- API notice :[@twitterapi](http://twitter.com/twitterapi)
- Trust and Safety Lead :[@delbius](http://twitter.com/delbius)
- Safety :[@safety](https://twitter.com/safety)
- Feedback :[@feedback](https://twitter.com/feedback)
- Twitter Mobile:[@twittermobile](http://twitter.com/twittermobile)
- CEO: [@ev](http://twitter.com/ev) (They rarely respond to the normals ... only [verfied](http://twitter.com/JustinBieber))
- Support: [@support](http://twitter.com/Support)
- Unofficial Support: @[TweetSmarter](https://twitter.com/TweetSmarter)

So this is where information flows. Anything else that happens on *meta* (e.g showing interesting stats, discussing proper etiquette, how to do stuff) is discussed on many blogs.

Answer (score 6):

There's [support.twitter.com](http://support.twitter.com/).

It provides info on how to use the site works, basic questions, tech support, and reporting issues.

Comment: I was more wondering about a community that discusses the evolution of the community and features.

Answer (score 1):

There's an official discussion group for Twitter developers and the API, called [Twitter Development Talk](http://groups.google.com/group/twitter-development-talk). This often touches on the evolution of features and so forth, though it's obviously primarily aimed at developers consuming the API. That's about the nearest I know of.